# ESP32 with max98357a board works. But I can't use void loop() function for other purposes

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, i2s

I have been learning how to program in esp32 using arduino IDE.

I couldn't figure out how to use max98357a board with Esp32-DevKitC. I have tried "Audio.h" and "AudioTools.h" libraries but not is changed.

My first attempt was just testing voice output. My code is below:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "Audio.h"
 
// Digital I/O used
#define I2S_DOUT      26  // DIN connection
#define I2S_BCLK      27  // Bit clock
#define I2S_LRC       14  // Left Right Clock
 
Audio audio;
 
String ssid =     "MYCROFT";
String password = "145678abc789";
 
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.disconnect();
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), password.c_str());
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) delay(1500);
    audio.setPinout(I2S_BCLK, I2S_LRC, I2S_DOUT);
    audio.setVolume(21); // 0...21
 
//    audio.connecttohost("http://www.wdr.de/wdrlive/media/einslive.m3u");
//    audio.connecttohost("http://macslons-irish-pub-radio.com/media.asx");
//    audio.connecttohost("http://mp3.ffh.de/radioffh/hqlivestream.aac"); //  128k aac
//     audio.connecttohost("http://mp3.ffh.de/radioffh/hqlivestream.mp3"); //  128k mp3
      audio.connecttohost("http://vis.media-ice.musicradio.com/CapitalMP3"); //  128k mp3
//    audio.connecttospeech("Wenn die Hunde schlafen, kann der Wolf gut Schafe stehlen.", "de");
//    audio.connecttohost("http://media.ndr.de/download/podcasts/podcast4161/AU-20190404-0844-1700.mp3"); // podcast
    
}
 
void loop()
{
    audio.loop();    
}
```

It works as intended but when I try to add some commands to the loop function, It stops working.

I mean if I change the loop function as below, it stops connecting to the audio stream.

```
void loop()
{
    delay(3000);
    Serial.println("Hello");
    audio.loop();    
}
```

Is it possible to use max98357a with some additional codes apart from just simple audio.loop().

Answer (score 0):

The delay(3000) instruction causes the microprocessor to do nothing but sit & wait for 3 seconds. Not even interrupts are serviced so audio is lost.